When will kalki born and where will he born?
In my opinion, Kalki will be born in Tamilnadu or srilanka. Because, in ancient books they said that Kalki will born in the end of kali yuga and especially in between three oceans. It means where the three oceans met there only Kalki will born. Indian Ocean, bay of bengal and Arabic ocean these three oceans are met in rameshwaram and srilanka. So there is a big chance of Kalki avatar in Tamilnadu or srilanka.


"And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take
his birth. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great
intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his birth in a town
of the name of Sambhala in an auspicious Brahmana family . And vehicles
and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his
disposal as soon as he will think of them. And he will be the king of
kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue. And he will
restore order and peace in this world crowded with creatures and
contradictory in its course. And that blazing Brahmana of mighty
intellect, having appeared, will destroy all things. And he will be
the Destroyer of all, and will inaugurate a new Yuga. And surrounded
by the Brahmanas, that Brahmana will exterminate all the mlecchas
wherever those low and despicable persons may take refuge."


Section CLXXXIX, Markandeya Samasya parva, Mahabharata.

